# dispatchertimer not continue when messagebox is shown

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my wp8 app, i have a countdown timer using dispatchertimer. I click a button and show a messagebox The countdown timer doesn't continue, when the messagebox is shown. I want the timer_counter continue to countdown during the time messagebox is shown.

I have tried System.Timers.Timer, but it cannot find the class. Also, I tried the DispatcherPriority to make the timer work at background. But it cannot find the class, too.

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;
private int timer_counter;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // set timer
    timer_counter = 30; // 30 secounds
    CountdownTimer.Text = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timer_counter).ToString("mm':'ss"); // show the time to textbox
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();  
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // interval: 1 second
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    timer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer_counter--; // countdown
    CountdownTimer.Text = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timer_counter).ToString("mm':'ss"); // show the time to textbox
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(
                     "clickbutton",
                     "alert",
                     MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```

Comment: Hey mat i tried your code and it works fine

Comment: The `MessageBox` is called synchronously and runs on the same thread as the Dispatcher. Therefore, until it returns, execution is paused. Try calling it asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the design of [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In your example the timer tick callbacks are run in the UI thread. And when the UI thread is in use - it waits...

Comment: Thank you. I successfully use System.Threading.Timer to implement.

Comment: If you want to learn about the different timers, here is a great article: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Timers